V.I.P. Club for Stars
Three a-list celebrities, A, B, and C, meet at their favorite pub on Hoc Rd. and decide to visit the same four places soon, partially together.
When the time comes for their trips...
A leaves her home on Sea Chime Rd. and visits Ust'-Barguzin, Russia, then meets C on Jarvis Island. Next she meets B and C in Mbandaka in the Dem. Rep. of the Congo, and lastly to Punta Arenas, Chile.
B leaves his home on Others St. and goes to Jarvis Island while C leaves his home on Caiden St. and begins his journey to Punta Arenas. B then goes to Punta Arenas while C meets A on Jarvis Island. Then B meets A and C in Mbandaka and then B and C travel to Ust'-Barguzin together.
What is the name of the V.I.P. club for stars?

Hm. Looks like the plebeians of PSE have no love for the stars.

lol. looks that way. :)

I'm feeling generous, so 500 rep points to the first complete and correct answer to this one. I won't put a bounty on it because the bounty system isn't well set up for this type of offer, since it could waste the 500, and even worse, it would award it to an answer that is not complete if there is no correct answer.

The V.I.P. club for stars is named ...

 ... after a star. Its name is The SUN Club.

The destinations

 The four different destinations are located at:

      0°22' S   160°00'W   —   Jarvis Island
    53°10' S     70°56'W   —   Punta Arenas
      0°03'N     18°15' E    —   Mbandaka
    53°24'N   109°02' E    —   Ust'-Barguzin

 These four places lie (more or less) on a great circle at about 53° 8' to the equator plane. They are evenly spaced at approximately 90°.

The pub and the homes

 The streets where the pub and the residences are hold some hints. They can be anagrammed to:

          Hoc Rd:         chord
          Sea Chime Rd:   Archimedes
          Others St:      shortest
          Caiden St:      distance

 A chord is the shortest distance of two points on a circle. (I don't quite see where Archimedes comes in, though.)

The itineraries

 Sketching out the travel routes of our celebrities on the great circle with straight lines (or chords, "as the mole burrows"), we get:


 If you tilt your head slightly to the left, you can see the letters S, U and N. These jet-setters do have style. Tracing out the name of the club on a global scale beats trying to jog a Valentine message on your fitness tracker, if you ask me.

Odds & ends

 The angle 53° 8' is one of the angles in the Pythagorean triangle (3, 4, 5), but it doesn't seem to be important here. The first letters of the destinations spell JUMP, which may or may not be a hint towards the direct movement between the places.

 Using both Starts and V.I.P. in the title is redundant, but the answer explains that. (But when I hear "Sun club", I think of tanning beds.)


Nicely found. There was me calculating shortest distances and poring over the resulting numbers looking for patterns... Way overthinking it! :)

Nicely done, and well-explained. I wondered how it would be visually represented, but I like the way you did it, even if it is 2-D. "Jump" was just a coincidence that I never realized. Archimedes is sometimes credited as the first person to say that the shortest distance between 2 points is a straight line. And a V.I.P. Club for literal stars might be called the "Sun Club", since only around 20% of stars are also suns. :) All the talk about celebrities was to divert attention away from literal stars, or at least give a double meaning.

Yes, the 2d representation is a compromise. I had a 3d model, but only of the lines, which made me realize that (the relevant part of) the Earth is flat. :) A picture of how the great circle connects the places would be nice, of course.
